# C Preprocessor directives and Linking

Tags: c++, c

The #include directive will result in placing the content of the header file in the source code before compilation : for example if I included stdio.h , the preprocessor will work on placing all the content of stdio.h in the source code then compile isn't it ?

So let's pretend that I'm just using the printf() function in my code. So there must be something that will happen after the compilation and between the linking that will delete all function implementations that were included from the header file and only insert the printf() function implementation in the Import table of the executable , knowing that all other functions were compiled with the source. Can you explain that to me please ?

Comment: It's not that the other functions are deleted. If you don't call a function, no code is generated that references it, so the linkage is missing by virtue of never having been created. It's like saying "The phone company sent me a phone book. I looked up my friend and called him. When I get my phone bill, I see only my friend listed on the bill. Who deletes all the phone numbers I didn't call?"

Comment: @RaymondChen, not exactly. link-time optimization will eliminate unused code on a per-object-file basis. As for your example, the phone bill may actually contain records for all family members.

Comment: @liuyu The issue here is not linker cleanup. There is nothing to clean up since it was never created.

Comment: There are (usually) no function calls in header files - just the declarations of the signatures (return types, parameter types, and function names) of functions (along with structures, constants, etc.).

Comment: @RaymondChen, you are assuming linkage against shared libraries, where the executable only contains references to the function implementations. But the question is better explained with static linking, i.e., how the linker deals with functions declared in `<stdio.h>` but not called in the program.

Comment: @liuyu Same logic applies regardless of whether the implementation is in a shared or static library. Declaring a function generates no code. There is nothing for the linker to remove since nothing was created.

Comment: @RaymondChen, your logic is being off-the-topic. The question asks about linking against an external programming library (i.e., the standard C library). More specifically, whether the linker does some optimization when *embedding* function implementations into the binary executable. It does!

Comment: @liuyu No, the question is about header files. "Why does including stdio.h not create a dependency on the standard library?" The answer is that the header file contains only declarations, as others have noted. Even if the linker does not discard unused functions, the problem does not exist. You can see this if you include math.h but forget to link to libm. The link still succeeds.

Comment: @RaymondChen, once again, you are assuming dynamic linking. The question asks about **"(what) happens after the compilation and between linking"**, in particular **how the linker deals with invoked and non-invoked functions, all available from the standard library**. I made it clear in my previous comment that this problem is better explained with static linking, where the linker actually performs optimization. Your `libm` example is completely irrelevant under this setting.

Comment: @liuyu The OP is under a mistaken understanding of the distinction between compilation and linking. The linker doesn't deal with the problem because the linker never sees the problem. The problem is solved in the compiler: A function that is never called (whether the function is in a dynamic or static library, doesn't matter) generates no external. The other answers to this question agree with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `printf` function is not actually in the header file, it's in a library that is automatically linked to the executable by the linker.

Header files should contain only function *prototypes*, i.e. the declaration of the functions and not the definitions. And as there's no function definitions in the header file, no code will actually be generated for them, and the compiler will make sure that only the functions you actually call will get an entry in the generated object file so the linker knows about it.

Comment: So the mission of the linker is to include the code for those functions to generate the executable right ?

Comment: @JohnnyCat Yes it is. It takes all object files generated by the compiler, and all libraries, and combine them into a single executable file.

Comment: Header files can contain function definitions.

Comment: @MirceaIonica While technically true (and they can contain variable definitions too) it's a recipe for linker errors. Reworded my answer a little.

Comment: Now I see that you've edited to have the "should" which makes my comment obsolete. P.S. You can have inline functions which are OK to be defined in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

A *function prototype* declared in a C header file acts as a compile-time constraint. It identifies the correct number of parameters and correct types of those parameters. The verification of such constraints happens during the compilation phase (i.e. `*.c -> *.o`).

The (static) linking phase eliminates unused binary objects from programming libraries on a **per-object-file** basis. A programming library is an archive of binary object files (*.o), each containing the implementation of a collection of functions, constants, etc. As for your question, the binary object file containing the implementation of `printf` (and everything else in the same object file) will be linked into your program. Other unused object files will be eliminated as a link-time optimization.

Comment: The elimination is usually performed per section, not per object file. One could take advantage of this by using something like [`__attribute__((section(...)))`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348a/CIHIDDJJ.html)

Comment: @anatolyg, I agree that linking is technically per-section. but since `-ffunction-section` is not a default option in `gcc` (not a default option when programming libraries are compiled), the granularity of a section is typically beyond single function implementations. Thus we usually cannot expect linking a called function without introducing redundancies, at least not in the case of desktop computing.

Answer (score 0):

The header file only contains a *declaration*, e.g. of the form

```
size_t printf(char const *format, ...);
```

This tells the compiler that if it encounters the word `printf` and it is used as a function, then it can generate a function call.

The call instruction contains a placeholder for the actual address of the function, which is then inserted by the linker when building the final executable.

The linker generally just keeps a running list of yet unresolved *symbols*, and adds to this list when it encounters one of these placeholders, and fills in the actual address when it finds a *definition* for the symbol. In the case of `printf`, that definition is found in the C standard library, so the linker ensures that the library is loaded at runtime and the call instructions point at the right address.